# Insert line from side to side of the sheet

Tags: formatting, texstudio

[image: Line]

How do I insert a line from end to end on the sheet? As in the picture.

Comment: At the beginning of a new paragraph, `\noindent\hrulefill`.

Comment: thank u, steven

Comment: If you were unhappy with the vertical placement, you could do small adjustments post or prior with `\vspace{...}`.  Alternatively, you could use the optional argument of `\rule`, as in `\rule[-3pt]{\linewidth}{1pt}`.  Here there is a -3pt vertical shift on a rule that is 1pt thick.

Comment: and how do I make the text centered between the two lines?

Comment: I presume you mean vertically centered.  And that is what my 2nd column is about.  You can use `\vspace` or `\rule` shifting.  Other options involve `tabular` constructions and such.  Here is one example: `\par\noindent\hrulefill\par\vspace{6pt}
Xxx
\par\noindent\hrulefill\par`